# how to limit access to 'create and edit' in many2one field in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

```
< field name="product_id"
        attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in', ('purchase', 'to approve','done', 'cancel'))],
               'required': [('display_type', '=', False)],
        }"
        context="{'partner_id':parent.partner_id, 
                  'quantity':product_qty,
                  'uom':product_uom,
                  'company_id': parent.company_id, 
                  'show_for_ia':True}"
        force_save="1" 
        domain="[('purchase_ok', '=', True), '|', ('company_id', '=', False), ('company_id', '=', parent.company_id)]" groups="ia_po_rights.po_prd"
/>
```

in purchase.order form, I want to limit the access of `create and edit`  of field 'product_id' in odoo 13, the only user allowed of specific can create/edit product in the purchase order form

i have tried

```
options="{'no_quick_create':True,'no_create_edit':True, 'no_create': True, 'no_open':True}"
```

in product option, it removes the create/edit option.

I created a group

```
<record  id="po_prd" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Create/Edit Product</field>
    <field name="category_id"  ref="module_ia_purchase_product"/>
</record>
```

and csv file ```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_product_product_user,product.product.user,product.model_product_product,ia_po_rights.po_prd,1,0,0,1

```
but above removes the field `product_id` from the form.
how to allow it for "po_prd" users to create/edit product in purchase order form without removing the field?


I have tried overriding fields_view_get method
class purchase_po(models.Model):
    _inherit="purchase.order"



     @api.model
     def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        res = super(purchase_po, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)

             doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
             nodes = doc.xpath("//field[@name='product_id']")
             if self.env.user.has_group('ia_po_rights.po_prd'):

                for node in nodes:

                     node.set('options', "{'no_create_edit': False}")

                res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
         return res


but that not set the options to "product_id" field in purchase order
please suggest how to achieve this
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your desired behaviour is not possible with standard odoo framework.

Using a group on field view definition will either show or hide the field. So this is no option for you. And using the field options you've mentionted will always "hide" create/edit without a group control behind it.

I would go with the field options, because products can also be created on other places, for example in the products menues, where you can use the normal odoo access possibilities.

Comment: is there a way to set options="{'no_quick_create':True,'no_create_edit':True, 'no_create': True, 'no_open':True}" in fields_view_get method in odoo

Comment: Oh yes, that should be possible. You will have to manipulate the xml in that medhod.